# How to merge patch multiple level json with nlohmann library

Tags: c++, json, nlohmann-json

I have a list of paths like:`"blabla/bleble/blibli", "blabla/blibli/bleble"` 
I've succeeded to transform one to this: `{"blabla":{"bleble":{"blibli":null}}}` with this function:

```
nlohmann::json transform(std::pair<std::string, int> aaa){
    nlohmann::json pathJsoned = {};
    auto splitedPath = split(aaa.first, '/');
    nlohmann::json* bla = &pathJsoned;

    for(int i = 0; i < splitedPath.size(); i++){
        if( !bla->is_null() && bla->at(splitedPath[i].c_str()).is_object() ){
            if(i == splitedPath.size()-1){
                std::cout << i << " || " << splitedPath.size() << std::endl;
                pathJsoned[splitedPath[i].c_str()] = "FILE";
            }else{
                std::cout << i << " || " << splitedPath.size() << std::endl;
                pathJsoned[splitedPath[i].c_str()] = nlohmann::json();
            }
        }
        nlohmann::json* a = &bla->operator[](splitedPath[i].c_str());
        bla = a;
    }
    return pathJsoned;
}
```

But now i want to merge it and it doesn't work.
I've tried:

```
nlohmann::json merge( const nlohmann::json &a, const nlohmann::json &b )
{
    nlohmann::json result = a.flatten();
    nlohmann::json tmp = b.flatten();
    for ( auto it = tmp.begin(); it != tmp.end(); ++it )
        result[it.key()] = it.value();
    return result.unflatten();
}
```

The result is useless, it's like the merge doesn't do anything, I've tried the merge_patch method of nlohmann::json library but it do half of the job:

```
{
    "blabla": {
        "bleble": {
            "blibli": null
        },
        "blibli": {}
    }
}
```

The expected result:

```
{
    "blabla": {
        "bleble": {
            "blibli": null
        },
        "blibli": {
            "bleble": null
        }
    }
}
```

Do you know if it's possible to merge the complete json ?

here is the whole code: https://pastebin.com/Qyc8EQN0

Comment: What exactly do you mean by `merge`? What is the result you think should happen?

Comment: For the example I've provided I want something like this: ```{
  "blabla": {
    "bleble": {
      "blibli": null
    },
    "blibli": {
      "bleble": null
    }
  }
} ```

Comment: My purpose is to aggregate file path to make json structure.

Comment: Yes, but what does the merge result **look** like. You have some sample code, and you have sample output that you imply is wrong, but you don't say what result you want.

Comment: You meen i might to modify my post ?

Comment: Please modify your post with the input and the expected output.

Comment: There may be something wrong with your algorithm. What does the value of `result` look like after the loop but before you `unflatten` it? Performing the steps by hand gives the result you want, so you will have to do some debugging.